# How can I modify a variable in a dataframe using a If condition?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to replace some variable using the IF condition.
For exemple I have this dataframe :

| Name | New_Name | Flag_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NK | Nike | 1 |
| ADD | Adidas | 1 |
| Microsoft | Microsoft | 0 |
| APP | Apple | 1 |

If the Flag_Name = 1 then I have to replace the Name column by the content of the New_Name column, and if the Flag_Name = 0 then keep the content of the Name column.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Flag_Name'] == 1, 'Name'] = df['New_Name']
```

Or with a mask:

```
m = df['Flag_Name'] == 1
df.loc[m, 'Name'] = df.loc[m, 'New_Name']
```

Or `df['Name'].where`:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].where(df['Flag_Name'] == 1, df['New_Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use `np.where`:

```
df['Name'] = np.where(df['Flag_Name'] == 1, df['New_Name'], df['Name'])
```

Output:

```
        Name   New_Name  Flag_Name
0       Nike       Nike          1
1     Adidas     Adidas          1
2  Microsoft  Microsoft          0
3      Apple      Apple          1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try a function and work with more than one conditional.

First it's a good practice put the columns name in lower case and clean it, assuming that maybe there are spaces in it , then you can avoid errors.

One of the ways you can do that is with a list comprehension.

```
cols =[col.strip().lower() for col in df.columns]
df.columns = cols
```

Output

| name | new_name | flag_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NK | Nike | 1 |
| ADD | Adidas | 1 |
| Microsoft | Microsoft | 0 |
| APP | Apple | 1 |

Ok! Now Let's work with the replacement. For that let's create a function that will iterate over the Dataframe.

```
def correctname(df,col): #we need to pass the Dataframe name and the column to check
     for i, row in df.iterrows():
         conditional =row[col] #here we have the value to check
         if conditional == 1:
         df.iloc[i,0]=df.iloc[i,1]# the 0 and 1 are the index columns 'name' and 'new_name'

correctname(df,'flag_name')

df
```

Output

| name | new_name | flag_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | Nike | 1 |
| Adidas | Adidas | 1 |
| Microsoft | Microsoft | 0 |
| Apple | Apple | 1 |